# JQMobile Multi page In different files

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I read the documentation of jqmobile, and saw the Multi-page example.
I understand that I need to specify data-role="page", in order for the div to become a page.
The problem is I have many pages and to put all of them in one page looks ugly and messy. 
Can I put the pages in seperate html files?

Thanks.

Comment: sure you can, it's called _Single page model_. But note that if you want to run/execute functions for a specific page, you need to place JS code inside _page div_ of that page.